# Illegal character in path at index antlr

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, glassfish, antlr, glassfish-3

I am using Netbeans to create a JSF 2.0 project. I don't know where this error is coming from. It looks like Glassfish has a problem. I'm using glassfish-3.1.1. I've seen this error mentioned in other questions and the general answer has been to escape spaces in the file path with %20 but where can I do that if this is in glassfish code and not something I wrote?

```
WARNING: Illegal character in path at index 29: file:/C:/Projects/PP/build/web/WEB-INF/lib/antlr-2.7.6.jar
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 29: file:/C:/Projects/PP/build/web/WEB-INF/lib/antlr-2.7.6.jar
    at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2809)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:2982)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3066)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3014)
    at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:578)
    at java.net.URL.toURI(URL.java:918)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.SnifferManagerImpl.getURIs(SnifferManagerImpl.java:268)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.SnifferManagerImpl.getApplicableSniffers(SnifferManagerImpl.java:202)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.SnifferManagerImpl.getSniffers(SnifferManagerImpl.java:150)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.setupContainerInfos(ApplicationLifecycle.java:606)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:368)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:382)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:370)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1064)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:96)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1244)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1232)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.ReDeployCommand.execute(ReDeployCommand.java:126)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:355)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:370)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1064)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:96)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1244)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1232)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:462)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:212)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:168)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:238)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:822)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:719)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1013)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: Was there a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-16238

Comment: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)